# How should i implement ranking system

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project and wanted to have a quick look by you people if the schema or query needs some changes or does it totally needs to be changed.

The project is about creating a ranking system for the badminton teams where the ranking will be based on the scoring rules in a tournament

- +2 Points/match would be awarded to the winning team.
- An Extra +1 Point would be awarded to the winning team if the match was a Quarter-finals.
- An Extra +2 Points would be awarded to the winning team if the match was a Semi-finals.
- An Extra +5 Points would be awarded to the winning team if the match was a Final.
- Winning all pool matches will add 4 points to your Team score.
- Winning more than 3 tournaments will add 15 points to your team.

I started by creating the following tables

**Players**

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------
| Field    | Type                                | Null | Key | +----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------
| id       | int(11)                             | NO   | PRI | 
| name     | varchar(250)                        | NO   |     | 
| image    | text                                | YES  |     | 
| plays    | enum('RH','LH')                     | NO   |     | 
| added_on | datetime                            | NO   |     | 
| status   | enum('active','inactive','retired') | NO   |     |   +----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+--------------
```

**Teams**

```
+------------+----------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type                       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
    +------------+----------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
    | id         | int(11)                    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
    | name       | varchar(150)               | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                |
    | image      | text                       | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    | status     | enum('active','in-active') | NO   |     | active            |                |
    | added_on   | datetime                   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
    | updated_on | datetime                   | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
    +------------+----------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Player To Teams**

```
+-----------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)                   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| player_id | int(11)                   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| team_id   | int(11)                   | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| status    | enum('active','inactive') | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| added_on  | datetime                  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+---------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Tournaments**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year  | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Matches**

```
+---------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type                                  | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)                               | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| team_one      | int(11)                               | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| team_two      | int(11)                               | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| winner_id     | int(11)                               | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| tournament_id | int(11)                               | NO   | MUL | 1                 |                |
| added_on      | datetime                              | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| match_type    | enum('pool','quarter','semi','final') | NO   |     | pool              |                |
| sets          | smallint(2)                           | NO   |     | 1                 |                |
+---------------+---------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Match Score**

```
+----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field    | Type              | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)           | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| match_id | int(11)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| team_id  | int(11)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| set_num  | enum('1','2','3') | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| score    | smallint(2)       | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| added_on | datetime          | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+----------+-------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

**Pools**

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(10) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| tournament_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

One thing that you will notice that i have not saved rank scoring anywhere and i am calculating it on runtime using the following query

```
SELECT
    T.id, T.name, T.status,
    IFNULL(T.image,'no-image.png') as DP,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.team_one = T.id OR M.team_two = T.id)) as played,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE M.winner_id = T.id) as won,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE ((M.team_one = T.id OR M.team_two = T.id)
        AND (M.winner_id != T.id))) as lost,
    (
          ((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE M.winner_id = T.id) * 2) +
          (((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type = 'quarter'
        AND M.winner_id = T.id)) * 2) + 1) +
            (((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type = 'semi'
        AND M.winner_id = T.id)) * 2) + 2) +
            (((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type = 'final' AND M.winner_id = T.id)) * 2) + 5)) as Points
FROM
    badminton_teams T
ORDER BY 
        (Points) DESC;
```

First

- is it right to calculate the scoring on runtime using query or
- should I save update it every time I save a match result in the database

or

- should I schedule a cron job for this purpose

Edit:

Updated the query to the following

```
SELECT
    T.id, T.name, T.status,
    IFNULL(T.image,'no-image.png') as DP,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE ((M.team_one =T.id or M.team_two = T.id) and M.winner_id IS NOT NULL)) as played,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE M.winner_id=T.id) as won, (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE ((M.team_one =T.id or M.team_two = T.id) AND (M.winner_id!=T.id))) as lost,
    ((SELECT (SUM(BMS.points_won)-SUM(BMS.points_lost))
    FROM
        badminton_match_score BMS
        JOIN badminton_matches M ON (M.id=BMS.match_id)
    where M.team_one=T.id OR M.team_two=T.id and M.winner_id is not null)/(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE ((M.team_one =T.id or M.team_two = T.id) and M.winner_id IS NOT NULL))) AS AVG_SCORE,
    (
            ((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE M.winner_id=T.id)*2) + 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type='quarter' AND M.winner_id=T.id))

            +
            ((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type='semi' AND M.winner_id=T.id))*2)
                +
            ((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM badminton_matches M
    WHERE (M.match_type='final' AND M.winner_id=T.id))*5)
            ) 
as Points
FROM badminton_teams T
order by (Points) DESC, lost ASC, AVG_SCORE DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it right to calculate the scoring on runtime using query

If you want it to be a real time application. In my opinion, yes if the points are not accumulated and will reset after a game. For Sql performance issues.

> should i save update it every time i save a match result in the database

Updates are for modification only of data, saving the data after a match for history will be sufficient.

> should i schedule a cron job for this purpose

If in terms of larger databases and productivity, yes.

Comment: one issue in this query is that it will give you 8 points even if a team has not played any match yet